# MLA: How to write translations of terms?

Tags: writing-style

I am finishing my MA thesis and in the process of polishing it.

I adhere to MLA style and I cannot find anything online concerning:

I am translating a few terms. How do you write a term when in isolation? Imagine I am translating the word *monere* from Latin, which I write in italics. How to I write its translation? Between quotes or not?

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE. As this site follows a strict question-and-answer format, there should be only one distinct question per question. I therefore took the liberty to remove your second question; feel free to ask it separately.